# Find isolated cycles in Graph

Tags: python-2.7

I need to find isolated cycles in Graph(g), given a list of nodes whose indegree = outdegree = 1.

```
g = {1:[2], 2:[3], 3:[4,5], 6:[7], 7:[6]}
nodes = [6,7]
print findIsolatedCycles(g, nodes)
[[6, 7, 6]]
```

Here is my code which works fine in simple cases like above, but given a huge dataset it gives error:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

My code:

```
def findIsolatedCycles(g, nodes):
"""Find isolated cycles given a list of one-in-one-out nodes"""
paths = []
for node in nodes:
    isolatedCycle = []
    def visit(n):
        while len(g[n]) > 0:
            nodes.remove(n)
            dst = g[n].pop()
            visit(dst)
        isolatedCycle.append(n)
    visit(node)
    isolatedCycle = isolatedCycle[::-1] # reverse and then take all but last node
    paths.append(isolatedCycle)
return paths
```

Comment: What about using topological ordering?

Comment: Could you please clarify, how do you use `nodes`? Do you want cycle that pass through every vertex in `nodes`? Through any of vertex in `nodes`? Why do you need `nodes.remove(n)`? Also, could you please recall the definition of *isolated cycle*? Do you mean a cycle which contains only 1-in 1-out vertexes? If so, why you deal with arbitrary degree vertexes (you should skip visit(n) if g[n]>1?) Note also that you are modifying list `nodes` inside the loop which iterates `nodes`: it's not very good practice and can lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: Nodes here will be all one-in-one-out nodes. They have indegree = outdegree = 1.  Yes I want a cycle that passes through all the vertexes in nodes, although there might be multiple isolated cycles too. Isolated cycles have only 1-in-1-out nodes. If I don't use nodes.remove(n) I am getting key error. I just wanted to keep track of the nodes that are remaining to visit. Let me know if I am still not clear.